# Flask-SocketIO server hosted on Windows 10 works on all ports except port 80 when outside local network

Tags: python, flask, server, network-programming, flask-socketio

I am trying to host a flask-socketio server on a Windows computer (currently only for the purpose of learning, it will later be moved to a Raspberry Pi) and am rather new to flask. Everything has gone smoothly until trying to access the server from outside of my local network.

The server is being run with the following code, as many other StackOverflow posts have explained is necessary:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   socketio.run(app, debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I have port forwarded correctly and the server is visible within my own network (on **all** ports) via either my global ip, local (192.168.X.X) address, or localhost. It is also visible to external users if the server is hosted on anything other than port 80, including the flask default of 5000. However, if I host on port 80, nothing is visible externally.

I have experimented extensively with the windows firewall inbound rules for both port 80 and the python executable. The only cause I haven't been able to rule out revolves around something specific to Windows 10 blocking inbound port 80 connections. There are no other competing servers running on the machine and no errors thrown by python/Flask-SocketIO in any setup/connection mentioned here.

**Questions:**
Are there any gotcha's I simply haven't been able to find regarding either Flask-SocketIO or the Windows system? What other parts of the "chain" should I look into to diagnose this?

Comment: Your ISP could be blocking port 80 incoming.

Comment: On Unix systems, ports below 1024 are privileged and can only be accessed by accounts with administrator privileges. Not sure if Windows is the same, you may want to try running under the admin account to test for this. Or alternatively, you can try another low port, like 81. If 81 works but 80 doesn't, then I would suspect your ISP is blocking you from hosting web servers.

Comment: @v25, just called them and was able to determine nothing useful (Cox).

Comment: @Miguel I've run ports 79 and 81 and both are working perfectly. This also goes with v25's suggestion. I may need to look towards other options for fixing or remedying this with my isp.

Comment: If it's for permanent use you should consider running on 443 with SSL, tho ISP may block this aswell. You could also look at the app `ngrok` which gives you a temporary public URL, SSL included, and maps it back in to any internal port, tho this may be better for a temp setup; it ultimately depends on your usecase.

Comment: @v25 That's a good idea. I looked at No-IP's port re-routing, however I was unsure at time if this was the case (and I think you have to constantly renew your no-ip service monthly. 

I'll check port 443, and also see if Flask-SocketIO is capable of making secure connections that a browser operating on 443 would expect (I'm not sure if SSL is enforced on that port). Thanks for the advice!

Comment: To run this properly, run your app with gunicorn and a gevent as per the [official Flask-SocetIO docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gunicorn-web-server) then stick this behind nginx.  Nginx would terminate SSL, then proxy to your gunicorn server in plain HTTP.  There's a bit on nginx setup in that guide, though to secure the config see Mozilla's great resource, [Server Side TLS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) and their [SSL config generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/)!  Have fun.

Comment: After a bit of a long journey, I just confirmed my ISP block both port 80 and 25. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments on the original question suggested, this situation is indicative of ISP's blocking the ports used, especially in the case where other port numbers below 1000 work (otherwise, this would hint to a firewall issue somewhere).

After some long calls with my ISP, I've discovered that port 80 and 25 are, indeed, blocked.